# To derive an inequality of the form $f(r) \leq cr^\alpha$

Tags: inequality

Let $f$ be a continuous positive function on $[0,1]$ which satisfies

$$ f(s/2) \leq \theta f(s)$$

for all $s\in [0,1]$, where $\frac{1}{2} < \theta < 1$. Can we show that

$$f(s) \leq Cs^\alpha \ \ \forall s\in [0.1]$$

for some positive $C$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$?

Comment: If there are no other conditions on $f$, then no. Consider any function with $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x \to 1$.

Comment: Oops sorry, let's assume that it is bounded. L

Comment: You must also add some condition on $\theta$. Otherwise, consider any nonzero constant function.

Comment: Sorry again, $\theta <1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $f(1/2^n)\leqslant\theta^nf(1)$ for every $n\geqslant0$.

> $(\ast)$ Assume that $f$ is nondecreasing and that $\theta\lt1$.

Then, for every $s$ in $(0,1)$ there exists some $n\geqslant0$ such that $s\leqslant1/2^n\lt2s$, hence $f(s)\leqslant f(1/2^n)\leqslant\theta^nf(1)$. And $2^{n+1}\gt1/s$ hence $\theta^{n+1}\lt\theta^{-\log_2(s)}$, that is, $\theta^{n+1}\lt s^{-\log_2\theta}$.

One gets $f(s)\leqslant Cs^\alpha$ with $C=\theta^{-1}f(1)$ and $\alpha=-\log_2\theta$. Finally, if $\theta\gt1/2$, then $\alpha\lt1$.

**Edit:** The hypotheses put on $f$ in the question seem to vary a lot (let us hope they finally stabilize), hence one could mention that the same approach works for every function, nondecreasing or not, provided:

> $(\ast\ast)$ Assume that $f$ is bounded on $[1/2,1]$ and that $\theta\lt1$.

To see why, replace the step $f(s)\leqslant f(1/2^n)\leqslant\theta^nf(1)$ of the proof above by $f(s)\leqslant\theta^{n}f(2^{n}s)\leqslant\theta^{n}M$ where $M=\sup\limits_{[1/2,1]}f$, valid since $1/2\lt2^{n}s\leqslant1$.

Then $\alpha$ stays the same and $C$ becomes $C=\theta^{-1}M$.

Anyway, the continuity of $f$ is not needed, except to guarantee $(\ast\ast)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second assumption is fair enough. Thanks for that.